# Ola, Tenho um Banco de dados - mysql e gostaria de diminuir um valor em uma coluna inteira

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-select

Gostaria de usar o comando `update` para diminuir uma hora no valores que ja tem na tabela de valores diversos  na coluna inteira.

EX:

```
Nome da Coluna         Gostaria da coluna assim
     HORA                      HORA

    13:45                     12:45
    15:00                     14:00    
    17:00                     16:00
```

O valor na coluna eh esse mesmo `13:00` gostaria de diminuir 1hr na coluna inteira ... com o comando update.

Comment: Supondo que seu campo seja do tipo time, tente: `UPDATE sua_tabela SET seu_campo = SUBTIME(seu_campo, '01:00:00');`

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas formas de se resolver isso, uma delas é utilizando a função [`SUBDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) Ela serve para decrementar qualquer tipo de informação de um campo `DATETIME`.

**Exemplo:**

```
UPDATE sua_tabela SET
    hora = SUBDATE(hora, INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Segue um exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a89ff/1).